# Minimum value of Complex Trigonometric Expression

Tags: calculus

> Minimum  value of of $\displaystyle f(\theta) = \frac{a}{\cos \theta}+\frac{b}{\sin \theta}+\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{\cos^2 \theta}+\frac{b^2}{\sin^2 \theta}}.$
>
> Where  $\displaystyle a,b>0, \theta \in \bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg).$

what i try

$$f(\theta)=\frac{2(a\sin \theta +b\cos \theta)+2\sqrt{\bigg(a\sin \theta+b\cos \theta\bigg)^2-a\sin 2 \theta}}{\sin 2 \theta }$$

How do i minimize is Help me please

Comment: You could try differentiating it - it might get messy though.

Comment: I wonder if some known inequalities, CS, Holder, etc can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
f'(\theta) &= a \tan \theta  \sec \theta + b \tan \theta \sec \theta \hfill \\
&\quad {}+ \frac{2 a^2 \tan \theta \sec^2 \theta + 2 b^2 \tan \theta \sec ^2\theta }{2 \sqrt{a^2 \sec ^2 \theta + b^2 \sec^2 \theta}}  \\
&= \tan \theta \sec \theta \left(\cos \theta \sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right) \sec^2 \theta }+a+b\right)  \\
&= \tan \theta \sec \theta \left( a + b + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}

$\tan \theta \neq 0$ for $\theta \in (0, \pi/2)$.  $\sec \theta \neq 0$ for any $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$.  Since $a>0, b>0$, the parenthesized expression is always positive.  Therefore, this function has no critical points.

So we check the endpoints to see which one *would* be the location of the minimum if it were a permissible point.  $f(0) = a + b + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \pi/2^-} f(\theta) = \infty$ (requiring the use of $a>0, b>0$).

So for $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$, $f$ has no minimum value, but it takes values arbitrarily close to $a+b+\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, a lower bound for values of $f$, as $\theta$ approaches $0$.